# Retrieve user who sent a message in rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq

Using Rabbitmq, is it possible to retrieve the Rabbitmq user who sent a message ?

We would like to use it for privilege management.

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean with `who sent a message` ? The IP ? the module ?

Comment: I mean the credential used to send the message. I dived in the doc and sa w a method set_user_id which should be what I was looking for.